# mv5 html.dropdownlist option elements have no id but have to be distinct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I am retrieving information from a database using the html dropdownlist helper. The table contains repeating information so I need to use the distinct functionality along with giving each option element a unique value which should probably be the value of the option element itself.

Here's the code I have developed so far. It is distinct but the option elements have no id.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct()))
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.stories).Distinct()))
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.size)))
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the code for the model:

```
    namespace BIRDSResidential.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ResidentialBuilding
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public short stories { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
        public string orientation { get; set; }
        public string shape { get; set; }
        public int floorht { get; set; }
        public string foundation { get; set; }
        public int windowpercent { get; set; }
        public string heating { get; set; }
        public string cooling { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the controller:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BIRDSResidential.Models;

namespace BIRDSResidential.Controllers
{
    public class ResidentialBuildingController : Controller
    {
        private BIRDSReslocalEntities db = new BIRDSReslocalEntities();

        // GET: ResidentialBuilding
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //ViewBag.ResidentialBuildings = new SelectList(db.ResidentialBuildings, "ID", "type");

            return View(db.ResidentialBuildings.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is bad practice to have data access code in your view layer. Move it into the appropriate business logic layer.

However, for your issue, the problem is that you aren't setting the dataValueField and dataTextField. You need to use a different overloaded SelectList constructor. Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Guessing from your sample code it should look something like this:

**Update:**

There are a few issues here. With regards to getting distinct records, you need to implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The reason to implement this is that you want to select a set of objects with and "Id" and "Description". Using distinct on a set of objects with only one property will not allow you to populate the drop down boxes correctly.

In the updated answer, I have not done this and only updated the code to get the Select boxes populated.

Updated (Controller):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BIRDSResidential.Models;

namespace BIRDSResidential.Controllers
{
    public class ResidentialBuildingController : Controller
    {
        private BIRDSReslocalEntities db = new BIRDSReslocalEntities();

        // GET: ResidentialBuilding
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.ResidentialBuildings = new SelectList(db.ResidentialBuildings, "ID", "type").Distinct();

            return View(db.ResidentialBuildings.ToList());
        }
}
```

Updated (View):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", (ViewBag.ResidentialBuildings as SelectList))
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding",(ViewBag.ResidentialBuildings as SelectList))
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuilding", (ViewBag.ResidentialBuildings as SelectList))
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you let me know what is a good practice to achieve the same result? I am new to .net mvc development

Comment: Also, the code above does not work. My code is:             `@Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuildings", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct(), "Id", "type"))`        The page returns a **System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'.** exception

Comment: Could you post your code of your models? What you need is to have the dropdown setup in your controller (actually in a business layer). It should be something like `SelectList(db.ResidentialBuilding, "Id", "type")` in your controller.

Comment: Please look at the updated question above. It contains the code for the model and controller. PS the data must have unique values for the option elements and must also be distinct since i have repeated records in the database.